# Is it better to have one large background image or many smaller images?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2d game and was wondering if it was better to have a single large background image which scrolls or make the background from multiple smaller images.

ie does Unity cull images if they out of camera view? If this is the case would a single large image be less performant?

Comment: This question is too broad. Would you mind providing more information or explaining what you're asking in more detail? 

Furthermore, have you tried either option?

Comment: Depends on what "better" means with respect to your game... what will deciding one way or the other affect?

Comment: I am currently trying one large image. It is a side scrolling game and I have an image which is very wide currently. I was thinking that if it was smaller images set side by side it may prove to have better performance as possibly unity would cull the images which are out of view? However I have no idea if unity will do this or not in 2D...

Comment: Totally depends on the resolution of the image with respect to the resolution of the 2D viewport.   No point loading a 4K image for a retro pixel art game where the viewport is a _logical 320x200_

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to draw calls and objects in the scene.

If you have more than 1 texture, that means that you need more than one object for each part. If the textures are all on the same atlas you don't have problems with draw calls but you need those objects in memory (altough you could have fewer objects and then show them up with the apropriate texture at runtime by code). If they are not on the same atlas you'll have more draw calls so it will be more cpu intensive.

If you have one large texture you'll have 1 draw call and 1 object so it's the least expensive.

Yes, Unity culls what's outside of the frustrum unless it's part of a batch (static bathing or dynamic batching).

Answer (score 1):

If you have one big texture with the drawn level, it will be rendered with one quad on the GPU, and UV coordinates/positions of vertices will be adjusted on hardware during rasterizer stage. There no actual culling happened or perfomance lost. But in case of small images, each of these will become an quad (2 triangles), then transformed, and then out of screen triangles will be culled, however thats depends on Unity - how they do the culling (hardware or software). But anyway, its better have one big background - there only 4 vertices to be tranformed and only screen width*height pixels to be rendered

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the latter.

Because you can use camera frustum culling and occlusion culling.

If you use image atlas, draw call will not be increased even if you use multiple bg textures. So DC call is the same.

Unity frustum culling and occlusion culling works based on objects not polygons. So if you make one big chunk of game object, culling possibility is decreased dramatically. As far as it is in camera frustum, it'll not culled.

If you split the background textures into small pieces, they'll be culled when they are out of main camera.(They should be static.)

And I think you can manage this kind of culling without Unity's culling functions. Because you can know when the backgrounds go out of camera.